# Showing that uniform random variables converge to zero

Tags: probability, limits, convergence-divergence

Defining $Y_{n}$ $=$ $nU^{n}$ where $U\sim$ UNIFORM$(0,1)$

How would one go about proving  that $Y_{n}\to 0 $ a.s  (as n$\to \infty $.) 
But does not converge to zero in $L^{p}$.

I can do the second part

$E(|Y_{n}-0|^{P})=n^{p} E(U^{np}) $ =

$$ n^{p} \int_{0}^{1} x^{np} dx= n^{p}\frac{1}{np+1}$$ 
$$\to \begin{cases} 1       & \quad \text{if } p \text{ is 1}\\
    \infty & \quad \text{if } p \text{ >1} \end{cases} \text{neither are zero}$$

For the a.s part i have tried just using the definition but i get stuck with the limit, i can see how it does converge to $0$ but cant write a rigorous proof. Thanks

Comment: You can find which realizations of $U$ make $n U^n\rightarrow 0$.  Clearly it is not true if $U=1$. What about other values of $U$?

Comment: Since $U\in (0,1)$ i don't think $U=1$ is relevant. U will be some value less than 1 but more than 0 however im finding it hard because U is continuous so it wont be an exact value.

Comment: @Michael $\mathbb P(U=1) = 0$ so that case is irrelevant.

Comment: Since $$\mathbb P(Y_n\leqslant y)=\mathbb P\left(n U^n\leqslant y\right) = \mathbb P\left(U\leqslant \left(\frac yn\right)^{\frac1n}\right),$$
the density of $Y_n$ is
$$
f_n(y) = \frac1{n^2}\left(\frac yn\right)^{\frac1n-1}\cdot\mathsf 1_{(0,n)}(y).
$$

Comment: @Monty So, $\{\omega: nU^n(\omega)\to 0\}=\{\omega: U(\omega)<1\}$? Is this not enough?

Comment: @Nch yes i guess it is since $n(a/b)^{n}$ $\to 0$  for 0<a<b.

Comment: @Math1000 : Notice that NCh solves the problem by answering the question I posed in my first comment "which realizations of $U$ makes $nU^n\rightarrow 0$"?  This is indeed the relevant question for this problem, and so (for any random variable $U$)  $$P\left[\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} nU^n=0\right] = P[|U|<1]$$ On the other hand, while your calculation of the density of $Y_n$ is nice, it is not clear how it helps to solve this problem of almost sure convergence.